# Why is $1+1+\dfrac{1}{2^{\alpha-1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2(\alpha-1)}} +\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2^{(\alpha-1)(K-1)}}<1+\dfrac{1}{1-(1/2^{\alpha-1})}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

This is from Real Analysis, proof of Theorem 2.25:
"Let 
$\alpha$ 
be a real number. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^\alpha$$

is convergent if 
$\alpha>1$
 and is divergent if
 $\alpha\le1$".
This was given information in the proof for the inequality of the series written on the topic 
$N\ge1$ ,$K\ge1$, and
 $1<\alpha<2$. I have put little effort understanding it but still couldn't understand why this is true and how did it just came out of a thin air.I hope experts like you can explain it and if you need any information related to this inequality please let me know in comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The part after the first $1$ is a geometric progression with ratio $1/2^{\alpha-1}$. The sum $1+1/2^{\alpha-1}+1/2^{2(\alpha-1)}+...$ is equal to $1/(1-1/2^{\alpha-1})$.

Comment: I think that should say "divergent if $\alpha\leq 1,$" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of a finite GP with positive terms is always less than the corresponding infinite GP. See below:
$$S=1+1+\frac{1}{2^{(a-1)}}+\frac{1}{2^{2(a-1)}}+\frac{1}{2^{3(a-1)}}+...+\frac{1}{2^{(a-1)(K-1)}}$$ 
$$=1+\sum_{j=0}^{K-1} 2^{-(a-1) j} < 1+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^{(a-1)}}}, a>1$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I think I was blind at that moment >_< couldn't observe that obvious pattern.